# MS SQL Config With Slick 2.0.1 And Playframework 2.2.2

Tags: sql, sql-server, playframework, slick, slick-2.0

When I try to use the new proprietary MS SQL driver, I get an exception which boils down to a ClassNotFound for the driver class.

I include both slick and slick-extensions:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "2.0.1"
```

Example use:

```
import com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.simple._

Database.forURL(url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:1433;databaseName=thedb1", driver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver", user="user", password="password" ) withSession { ...
```

Exception:

Ultimately, ClassNotFound for com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.

Comment: https://github.com/freekh/play-slick seems to be the answer.

Comment: To get Slick 2.0 connected to Microsoft SQL Server within Playframework 2.2.x, use play-slick >= 0.6.0 (https://github.com/freekh/play-slick) and the JDBC SQL driver from microsoft (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver).

play-slick has a sample application:  https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database

This question covers the correct driver to use for sqlserver:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045561/scala-slick-connect-to-mssql-server

Comment: Apparantly driver config needs to specify both the MS JDBC driver and the one in slick extensions? db.default.slickdriver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: It turns out you can use the open source jTDS driver as well.  (By setting db.default.driver to net.sourceforge... and leaving db.default.slickdriver set to the Slick driver.)

Comment: https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/ffe2a505287bc3b76c4cf95ddb9105a8ab0ae92a/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/Config.scala#L11

Comment: Asked about it here https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/151

Comment: @Andre -- thanks.  I figured this out but don't have the rep to answer my own question.  If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.  (To help future googlers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across the same issue and was able to solve it by defining the following lines in the application.conf file (thanks to the help from the play-slick contributors [here](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/issues/151#issuecomment-41768333)):

```
db.default.slickdriver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Alternatively, you could use the jTDS driver from sourceforge like listed in the question's comments.

```
db.default.slickdriver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I ended up doing the first option, which meant downloading the unmanaged dependency `sqljdbc4.jar`(available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)) and placing it on the `{play app root}/lib` directory. 
Since the jTDS driver is available as a library dependency for build.sbt, I'd suggest trying that one first.

Comment: Minor additions:  be sure to use play.api.db.slick.DB instead of play.api.db.DB, as well as the convenience class DBAction instead of Action in any controller methods that access the database.

Comment: What's the right solution if doing this outside of Play?  I'm just pulling in slick + slick-extensions.